# COUNT and GROUP_CONCAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am having three tables `pcn_type`, `in_e_s_s__p_c_ns`, `p_c_n_details`. I am trying to concat three different values into single using group concat.

**My Query:**

```
SELECT 'browser' AS NAME, CONCAT( '[', CONCAT('{"', pcn_type.name, '",', 
COUNT(JPN_ID), '}'), ']' ) AS DATA FROM p_c_n_details INNER JOIN 
in_e_s_s__p_c_ns RIGHT OUTER JOIN pcn_type ON pcn_type.name = 
p_c_n_details.type AND in_e_s_s__p_c_ns.pcnid= 
p_c_n_details.JPN_ID GROUP BY pcn_type.name
```

**Result got:**

```
NAME    |    DATA
-------------------------------------
browser      [{"Design Change",4}]
browser      [{"EOL",10}]
browser      [{"Process Change",21}]
```

**Expecting Result:**

```
NAME    |    DATA
--------------------------------------------------------------------
browser      [{"Design Change",4},{"EOL",10},{"Process Change",21}]
```

How to restructure the above query to get the expected result.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Now all that is left is to implement addslashes in MySQL :)

Comment: @Strawberry I am using this data in Highcharts dynamically.

Comment: If available, I would build the jsonish string in some kind of application code.

Comment: Yes,i tried to do in application code, Found difficult..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `GROUP_CONCAT` function

```
 select name,GROUP_CONCAT(DATA  SEPARATOR ' ') 
from 
(          
    SELECT 'browser' AS NAME, CONCAT( '[', CONCAT('{"', pcn_type.name, '",', 
    COUNT(JPN_ID), '}'), ']' ) AS DATA FROM p_c_n_details INNER JOIN 
    in_e_s_s__p_c_ns RIGHT OUTER JOIN pcn_type ON pcn_type.name = 
    p_c_n_details.type AND in_e_s_s__p_c_ns.pcnid= 
    p_c_n_details.JPN_ID GROUP BY pcn_type.name
) as T group by name
```

Comment: Thanks you Zaynul.